# Promise chain not executing in expected order

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to use a sequence of promises to authenticate a user name and password, but the promises seen to be resolving too early.

I have two methods from two different files involved here.

First, my controller, which picks up the request and invokes my model for the authentication. The model is supposed to return a promise that will have authentication results when it resolves.

Here is my controller:

```
router.post('/api/auth-tokens', function (req, res, next) {
    var creds = {user: req.body.user, password: req.body.password};
    people.authenticate(creds)
    .then(function (result) {
      var status = result.valid ? 200: 401; 
      res.sendStatus(status);
    });
});
```

`people` is the lexically scoped model. Here is the current implementation of the method used above:

```
var bluebird = require('bluebird');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt');
var compare  = bluebird.promisify(bcrypt.compare);

exports.authenticate = function (args) {
    var promise = orm.select({
        db: db,
        table: table,
        where: {id: args.user},
        qrm: 'one'
    });

    promise.catch(function (err) {
        var auth_info = { valid: false };
        return auth_info;
    });

    promise.then(function (user) {
        var promise = compare(args.password, user.hash)
        .then(function (same) {
            var auth_info = { valid: same, permissions: user.permissions };
            return auth_info;
        });
        return promise;
    });

    return promise;
};
```

`orm` returns a promise that will throw an error if the user doesn't exist, or resolve and yield the database row if the user was found. (That is why I have that `promise.catch` invocation in there. It's in case the user doesn't exist)

If the user does indeed exist, I want to invoke [`bcrypt.compare`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#to-check-a-password) to compare the input to the hash contained in the database row. When that finishes asynchronously, I want to resolve the promise chain and yield control back to the controller, returning the `results` object.

The issue I'm having though is that the `.then` in my controller is being executed immediately with the results of the initial promise returned by the call to `orm.select`. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because you've hooked up that callback directly to the promise returned by `orm.select`. Instead, you need to use the promise returned by `then`.

This is one of the biggest key things about promises: **`then` returns a new promise**. (So does `catch`.) If your handler function returns a promise (technically, any *thenable*) from either `then` or `catch`, the new promise that `then` (or `catch`) returns will resolve/reject based on the promise you return. If your handler function returns a non-promise value, the new promise from `then` (or `catch`) is resolved (not rejected) with that value.

So `authenticate` should probably look like this:

```
exports.authenticate = function (args) {
    return orm.select({
        db: db,
        table: table,
        where: {id: args.user},
        qrm: 'one'
    })
    .then(function (user) {
        return compare(args.password, user.hash)
        .then(function (same) {
            var auth_info = { valid: same, permissions: user.permissions };
            return auth_info;
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        var auth_info = { valid: false };
        return auth_info;
    });
};
```

Note that the changes are both to your outer function and what you do in `then`. Also note that the code in your `catch` callback will be called whether it's the original promise from `orm.select` that was rejected, or the one from `compare`.

To see what's going on, compare this snippet with the one after:

```js
// Returning the original promise
// Usually NOT what you want
function foo() {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    console.log("Starting first promise");
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Resolving first promise");
      resolve("first");
    }, 500);
  });
  promise.then(function() {
    promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
      console.log("Starting second promise");
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Resolving second promise");
        resolve("second");
      }, 500);
    });
  });
  return promise;
}
foo().then(function(result) {
  console.log("Got result: " + result);
});
```

Second:

```js
// Returning the original promise
// Usually NOT what you want
function foo() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    console.log("Starting first promise");
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Resolving first promise");
      resolve("first");
    }, 500);
  })
  .then(function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      console.log("Starting second promise");
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Resolving second promise");
        resolve("second");
      }, 500);
    });
  });
}
foo().then(function(result) {
  console.log("Got result: " + result);
});
```

Comment: @WilliamB: Big time, just tested it. Doh! Fixed, and thank you!

Comment: It's not clear from the docs & i'm not even sure why fn2 gets called in this case. But having a single final "catch" at the end of the promise chain is the best way to avoid unexpected behavior, or using `.then(successFn, errFn)`

Comment: @WilliamB: Yeah, it's just that then it covers both promises. But A) That's usually what you want, and B) It's probably want the OP wants here. So... :-) (Every time I think I understand promises and have even had that "ah hah!" moment, I find something that proves that I still have more to learn. They seem so...simple.)

Comment: @WilliamB Just to be clear, I can put any amount of `catch`es anywhere in the chain, it's just that they won't prevent the next promise in the chain from executing?

Comment: @LukeP, the best answer is "only put catch() at the END of the chain" since by default it returns a successfully resolved promise whether the original resolves or rejects. Any .then() after the .catch will get called with undefined if the promise fails, and will get called with the resolved value of the promise if the promise succeeds. Best to avoid this pattern

Comment: @LukeP: If you do `promise.catch(fn1).then(fn2)`, whether `fn2` gets called depends on what you return from `fn1`: If you return a rejected promise (or an unsettled promise that rejects later), `fn2` won't get called. If you return a value (or don't return anything), `fn2` gets called with that value (or `undefined`); if you return a new promise (either resolved or that resolves later), `fn2` gets called with that promise's resolution.

Comment: @LukeP if you want to catch things in the middle of the chain add a catch function to the .then as a second parameter, ie `prom.then(successFn, errFn).then(successFn, errFn)` etc.

Comment: @LukeP: I've expanded the "key" paragraph above. The most common pattern is indeed `.then().catch()`, but you can use `.catch()` to *handle* errors, and if you return a value (or new promise) from it, the promise `catch` returns will resolve or reject as appropriate.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's really just a byproduct of how nested promises work to resolve to the innermost value. I would not recommend that pattern unless there are errors you want to catch without causing the original promise to fail. Having a `prom.catch(function (e){ return Promise.reject(e); }).then(fn2)` purely for ordering purposes is less than intuitive and even looks like the common antipattern of nesting unneeded promises. someone might remove the Promise.reject wrapper without realizing it is necessary

Comment: @WilliamB: *"...unless there are errors you want to catch without causing the original promise to fail..."* If your `catch` has been called, the original has **already** failed. In any case, again, it wasn't needed here and I've explained how `then` and `catch` work (which includes why my original alternate suggest was wrong).

Comment: When I say "the original promise" in that post, I am referring to the original promise *chain*. No matter how many promises are in a chain of .thens, then will all only resolve if the original promise resolves, and fail if the original promise fails. However promises chained after the .catch will all resolve (unless one of the links in the chain resolves to a rejected promise).

Comment: @WilliamB: *"...I am referring to the original promise chain. No matter how many promises are in a chain of .thens, then will all only resolve if the original promise resolves, and fail if the original promise fails."* No, those statements are both incorrect. If a `catch` returns a value (or a promise that resolves), the remainder of the chain sees a resolution, not a rejection; similarly, if a `then` returns a promise that rejects, the remainder of the chain sees a rejection, not a resolution. *"However promises chained after the .catch will all resolve no matter what."* Same problem.

Comment: "If a catch returns a value (or a promise that resolves), the remainder of the chain sees a resolution, not a rejection" this is the exact problem i was pointing out

Comment: @WilliamB: Apologies if I misunderstood "original" in *"will all only resolve if the original promise resolves"*. My point is `p.then(f1).catch(f2).then(f3)` can see a resolution at `f3` even if `p` (the "original" promise) rejects, if `f2` handles it and returns a value/resolution. Probably just a wording misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is executing on a different promise than the one which uses bcrypt.compare

do it like so to ensure that the people.authenticate returns a promise chain which resolves to the inner result post-comparison:

```
var promise = orm.select(/* ... */)
    .then(/* bcrypt usage here */)
    .catch(/* error handling here */);

return promise;
```